# Error wiping device: Failed to probe the device 'dev/-sdb' (udisks-error-quark, 0)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, bad-sectors, secure-erase, ata

[image]My Hard disk was totally fine since I tried to format it using the 'ATA Enhanced Secure Erase' option on gnome disk utility. Now I can not formate or use it.
Every time I try to format it this error is showed: "Error wiping device: Failed to probe the device 'dev/-sdb' (udisks-error-quark, 0)"

Answer (score 4):

Note you must have a PARTITION to format
*(generally, with USB/Flash drives it may work without, but better have it there too for ease of use)*.

If you STILL have a problem after that; as I see `/dev/sdb` above,
try **exactly** this (to clear any invalid partitioning data):
`$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M count=1`
and then try to REDO the partitioning and format the relevant partition(s).

Comment: I tried it with status=progress. But after transfering 7 or 8 gb, it do not do any thing.

Comment: Then you may actually have a bad sector (as can be seen in the image), there may be tools to have that marked as bad (i.e. to not be used but the drive firmware). But generally it is better to replace a drive that has had one or more bad blocks - such a drive may abruptly fail totally.

Comment: my HDD has one bad sector. how can I fix or mark that bad sector?

Comment: Sorry, can't help with that, never been down that route :-]

Answer (score 0):

With a little luck you can unlock the harddisk with sudo hdparm --security-unlock "xxxx" /dev/ and then with sudo hdparm --security-disable "xxxx" /dev/ (instead of  you have to specify your harddisk in question. For example sda).

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/ng3wal/my_1tb_hdd_is_dead_please_help/